# How to broadcast message to all channels names matched in source pattern?

Tags: regex, websocket, pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

joined channel names:

`ABCD, ABCDE, ABC, XYZ, AI, ABCDEFG, BCD, CDEF`

How to (list?) match all joined channels and if is it possible to broadcast a message to `ABCD, ABCDE, ABC, ABCDEFG` channels that are included in basic pattern `ABCDEFG`?

Example of one channel:

`SomeApp.Endpoint.broadcast("names:" <> "ABCDEFG", %{ result: "bingo" })`

Comment: Sorry--isn't your syntax wrong?  Should it be ``SomeApp.Endpoint.broadcast("names:" <> "ABCDEFG", %{result: "bingo})`` (note the trailing parentheses)?

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix's PubSub does not support splat topic matching, so the only way to get what you want is to comprehend over the explicit topics `ABCD, ABCDE, ABC, XYZ, AI, ABCDEFG, BCD, CDEF` and call `SomeApp.Endpoint.broadcast("names:" <> subtopic, %{result: "bingo"}` on each of them.